# Why I am not getting data displayed in my grid?

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, desktop-application

I am using a grid to be bounded through code whose columns are defined at design time.

My code for binding the grid in the form_load() is :

```
private void SearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     try
     {
         cn = db.createConnection();
         if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            cn.Close();
            cn.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as BillDt from BillMaster", cn);
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

     }
     dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillNo"].ToString();
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PartyName"].ToString();
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["State"].ToString();
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillDt"].ToString();
     }

     ds.Dispose();
     cmd.Dispose();
     da.Dispose();
     cn.Close();
}
```

I debugged the program and the data is assigned to the each field that is observed from the Immediate Window while debugging but when the form is displayed the data does not appear. And number of blank row as fetched from the dataset are created.

How do I solve this? Please help.

Comment: where is dataGridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; // dataset
dataGridView1.DataMember = "TableName";//TableName

Hope it will work.